# Auto update value on HTML, firebase value

Tags: javascript, html, events, firebase-realtime-database

I have a value on my webpage which is taken from my Firebase DB. It displays great and is accurate. However this value is dynamic and changes  on certain actions.

How can i reflect this number value change on my webpage? I tried using an event listener but only found that working where there is  input from user.

HTML:

```
<p>Repetitions left: <strong id="progressList"></strong></p></strong></p><br>
```

Javascript, gets and display on page:

```
var WemosGet;
    firebase.database().ref('Reps').once('value').then (function(snapshot){
        WemosGet = snapshot.val().Value;
        document.getElementById("progressList").innerHTML=WemosGet;
        console.log(WemosGet);

    })
```

I tried something like:

```
output.innerHTML = WemosGet.value
    update=()=>{
        output.innerHTML = WemosGet.value; 
    }

WemosGet.addEventListener('input', update);
```

Doesnt seem to work. What approach should i seek?